# ComponentWillReceive Props not firing

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a component *Parent* that is connected to the redux store. Component *Parent* has access to state *X* from the redux store. Component *Parent* calls component *Child* inside it and passes *X* as a prop.

Now I expect that inside component *Child*, componentWillReceiveProps to be called everytime *X* changes, but this life cycle method isn't being triggered any suggestions?

```html
 export class Parent extends React.Component{
  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props)
  }  
  render(){
    return (
             <Child passedProps = {this.props.x} /> //x comes from a redux store
             )
  }
 }
             
 export class child extends React.Component{
  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props)
  }
  
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)
  {
    console.log("I expect this to be called everytime x changes in the parent i.e everytime passedProps changes in this component, but this is not getting fired at all);
  }
  
  render(){
  return (
            <div> this.props.passedProps </div>
            )
  }
 }
```

Comment: Show us the relevant part of the code.

Comment: Are you using React 17? this lifecycle method has been deprecated there and you can only use UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps. See https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops

Comment: I checked with UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps, doesn't work her as well.

Comment: Does the UI update?

Comment: Yes, the UI does update when X changes, but componentWillReceiveProps is not being called.